# How to store real time data to a database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, websocket, buffer

I have a server which is observing IoT data and I need to store it to a database so that I can build metrics of some kind.

The data is being received on a websocket connection, one piece of data might look something like this:

```
{
  id: 23,
  type: "light"
  status: "on"
  timestamp: 1607975079
}
```

There can be a large amount of data being observed and I thought that it may not be a great idea to add each event to the database in real time as it may cause bottlenecks.

Are there strategies with this type of scenarios where I can use an in memory buffer of some kind and then save a chunk of data to the database every 30 minutes?

Is this a sensible approach or are there other ways that this should be handled?

[image: diagram]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Redis as a buffer, and create a separated worker to save in bulk the data from the buffer to your database.

The idea is shown in the Docker Voting App:
https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app

You can build all the components in node.js, take into account the language mix in the example above is to show Dockers capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a buffer and add events there. When a certain number of events accumulate upload the buffer to the database.

Pseudocode:

```
const buffer = [];

event.on('event', data => {
  buffer.push(event);

  if (buffer.length === 10) {
    DataBase
      .bulkCreate(buffer);

    buffer = [];
  }
});
```

Or you can use [Cron](https://crontab.guru/#*/30_*_*_*_*):

```
const buffer = [];

event.on('event', data => {
  buffer.push(event);
};

const job = () => {
  DataBase
    .bulkCreate(buffer);

  buffer = [];
};

cron.schedule('*/30 * * * *', () => {
  job();
}).start();
```